# npm install on Elastic Beanstalk omitting folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm-install, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, keystonejs

This only started happening tonight, and even after reverting my totally not-npm related changes it's still happening.

I've got an AWS Elastic Beanstalk setup here where I'm calling `eb deploy` to deploy a KeystoneJS cms application.  As part of the deployment it runs `npm install`, and I've got a custom fork/branch of the keystone github repo that it's supposed to install.  And it does!  But for some inexplicable reason `/lib/core/` in the Keystone repo is just... not there.  I get errors complaining about those missing files, and sure enough the entire folder is not present.  They are just not npm installed, despite the rest of the Keystone repo being installed just fine.

I can't reproduce this locally.  I'll run `npm install`, it adds that folder.  I'll do `npm install <my-fork>`, it adds the folder.  Every combination locally works just fine, and every deployment I've done to EBS in the PAST has worked just fine.  Only tonight has this folder stopped showing up in my installations.

Is it a problem with Elastic Beanstalk?  Is it a problem with npm?  I've made sure to sync my local npm version (`6.8.0`) with the EB one, no difference.  I've checked to make sure I don't have any `.ebignore` or `.npmignore` or `.gitignore` that might somehow be blocking the `core` folder, nothing.  Unless there's one secretly controlling the temp folder that gets first installed to?  I don't know why this would suddenly be an issue though, when it wasn't a couple weeks ago.

Anyone experienced anything like this?

[Edit] For some additional details, changing the keystone version in my package.json to just `keystone: "4.0.0"` gets me those core files fine.  If I install directly from the associated keystone repo, `keystone: "keystonejs/keystone"`, they aren't there.  This is again just on the eb install tho, the core files show up for both if I do them locally.  But on eb when I install from a git url, which I need to for my specific fork/branch, I see this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out!

https://npm.community/t/npm-pack-leaving-out-files-6-8-0-only/5382

Someone broke npm 6.8.0.  Let my tale be a cautionary one, don't have your deployment scripts set to auto-update npm to the latest version.